# Schema extensions in Azure Ad Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is there any way we can see schema extensions or open extensions on Azure AD portal? Or we can create user from Azure AD portal using those extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Currently that's not possible but you can make or support a request in the [AAD Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/41512456-add-support-to-manage-open-and-schema-extension-tr) so that the product team triages it and responds to it.